# How to add info while copying from multiple fields using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

How can I add JavaScript to a single button as to copy text to the clipboard from multiple HTML inputareas including fixed text, while inserting a line break between each field?

To give you a better idea, it's simply a webpage that will allow us at work to take very repetitive notes that we always write (same points) made of 10 points, and with a click it'll copy the fields and the text that refers to the input in a form that is ready to be pasted anywhere.

Comment: Please add code.

Comment: Can we see some of your existing code? Do you have a form already? Are you using jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <head>
    <title>Repeater</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id = "button" onclick = "myFunction()">CLICK ME!</button>
    <input class = "text" name = "text" type = "text" id = "textone">
    <input class = "text" name = "textone" type = "text" id = "texttwo">
    <input class = "text" name = "texttwo" type = "text" id = "textthree">
    <input class = "text" name = "textthree" type = "text" id = "textfour">
    <input class = "text" name = "textfour" type = "text" id = "textfive">
  <script>
    var total;
    function myFunction(){
      var inputarray = document.getElementByClass("text);
      for(var i = 0;i < inputarray.length; i++){\
       var now = inputarray[i].value;
       total = total + now;
       total = tatal + "____________________________________________________________________________"
      }
    total.select();
    document.execCommand("Copy");
    }
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Try this